# Where can I find the "Leave a Reply" line in the Wordpress SmartBiz.1.1.1 theme?

Tags: wordpress, comments

I can't locate the *Leave a Reply* line in any of the `.php` files. It appears as a prompt for the user to leave a comment. I have also checked the `.css` files. I thought it should be in the `comments.php` or `page_template.php`... but it is not!
I do have that line appearing on my website... I want to modify it.

Comment: I don't understand where did those upvotes came from... BlaTh, use a decent editor (notepad++, sublime) and you'll find this in 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `wp-includes/comment-template.php`.

If that doesn't work, try to SSH into your server with PuTTY, cd into your website directory, and run the command `grep -R Leave\ a\ Reply *`. It will list every line of every file that has the phrase "Leave a Reply".